# Reusing a UITableViewCell's IBOutlets with two different UITableViewControllers

Tags: swift, code-reuse, iboutlet, uitableview

I'm creating a coffee timer as a learning exercise and I want to have a different menu based on the brewing method selected. I'm storing my settings in NSUserDefaults and populating my tables with two separate arrays that look like this:

```
var aero = ([
        "Cool Down Time Enabled" : true,
        "Cool Down Time" : 30,
        "Inverted" : true,
        "Base Steep Time" : 150,
        "Base Inverted Steep Time" : 180,

        ])

var french = ([
        "Cool Down Time Enabled" : true,
        "Cool Down Time" : 30,
        "Base Steep Time" : 180,

        ])
```

I created **two** UITableViewControllers, one for FrenchPress and one for AeroPress, they are largely the same code:

[FrenchPressTableViewController.swift](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/5c504709b9ae01cddcf8) - settings menu

[AeroPressTableViewController.swift](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/d8ddb1ca7366281e3121) - settings menu

Both assign values to instances of my Setting.Swift class ([gist](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/359a29f57883805e32e3)) and get stored in different arrays.

In IB I started with my french press controller and created two prototype cells and two prototype classes to go along with them.

[SwitchCell.Swift](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/9cc7c3df04e87ed6216a) - Model for my UISwitch prototype cell outlets

[TimingCell.Swift](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/600db61b8bb80bf4d7fb) - Models my TimingButton prototype cell outlets

**Initial Steps taken:**

- Create new tableView in IB for my French Press settings.
- Create a designated [FrenchPressTableViewController](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/5c504709b9ae01cddcf8), and assign it to my new French Press table view
- Set up two new prototype cells and set up IBOutlets/Actions using my [SettingCell](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/9cc7c3df04e87ed6216a) & [TimingCell](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/600db61b8bb80bf4d7fb) classes.
- The IBOutlets are connected from my FrenchPressTableViewController to my SettingCell.swift (I later reuse these outlets for my Aero settings).

My FrenchPress Settings **Works Fine**:
[image]

So I decided to add my Aero press settings menu using the same process:

- Create new tableView in IB
- Create a [AeroPressTableViewController](https://gist.github.com/codebeaulieu/d8ddb1ca7366281e3121), and assign it to my new aero table view
- Set up two new prototype cells and assign my previously existing SettingCell & TimingCell to the proper cells.
- I utilize the outlets that I previously connected to my FrenchPressTableViewController and I connect them to my Aero controller as well to reuse the cell classes.

The final product looks like like this:

[image]

But when I run my Aero settings menu, I get the following error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image]

[image]

### Question:

From what I can tell from my debugger, it looks like my **SettingCell** class is returning a **nil** value with `cell.switchLabel.text`. This doesn't make sense to me since I'm trying to assign a value to it.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, what is the proper way to reuse my UITableViewCell classes?

Comment: remove that line tableView.registerClass(SwitchCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier:"SwitchCell2") and add the cellIdentifier in storyboard..it works..

Comment: you nailed it... I actually added registerClass last week troubleshooting a very similar issue which led to this one. I must have fixed the previous issue while troubleshooting. Well... if you post this as the answer I'll accept it, or I'll read a few of your other posts and see if there are any I'd like to vote on. Thank you Anish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue arises while registering  the UITableViewCell class as  `tableView.registerClass(SwitchCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier:"SwitchCell2")`

Remove that line `tableView.registerClass(SwitchCell.self,forCellReuseIdentifier:"SwitchCell2")` and set the cellIdentifier in storyboard..it works